m2 Macbook looks terrible with HDR content... how do I turn it off?
It seems like when I view hdr content (typically I see this on youtube, but have also seen it on some image viewer apps) it makes content insanely bright, but dims everything else, and then it flickers when I switch away from the HDR content. There has to be a way to disable this... right?

Did you disable it in settings to test on battery with optimize enabled? https://support.apple.com/en-us/102205 (look for the Check your mac section … I’m assuming you aren’t using an external display and are viewing things on the built in display.

It doesn’t happen on my mac. It should not dim your UI too much.

i am using the built in display. I turned off hdr in display settings, and i have the battery saver option turned on so that it disables hdr while on battery. still no dice. shows hdr even while on battery power. lol

You could give BetterDispay a try, might have an option to disable it
https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay

About BetterDisplay
BetterDisplay is a truly wonderful tool! It lets you convert your displays to fully scalable screens, manage display configuration overrides, allows brightness and color control, provides XDR/HDR brightness upscaling (extra brightness beyond 100% for compatible XDR or HDR displays on Apple Silicon and Intel Macs - multiple methods available), full dimming to black, helps you create and manage virtual screens for your Mac, create Picture in Picture windows of your displays and gives you a host of other features to manage your display's settings like display and color mode easily from the menu bar. It can even disconnect/reconnect displays on-the-fly!

